# bash script to replace script tags in html with their content

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, html

is it possible to use `sed` to match the source of a script tag within  html (which is not valid xml) and replace the whole match with the files' contents?

e.g. say the html contained

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href="blah.css">
<script src='foo.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bar.js"></script>
<title />
```

I want to not only match 'foo.js' from within `src='foo.js'` but also to replace in this file the contents *of* foo.js, so to end up

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='blah.css'>
<script>var foo = {};</script>
<script>var bar = [];</script>
<title />
```

In a regex I can match the script tag src value like so:

```
<script\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?src=(["'])(.*?)\1
```

with the match being in the second capture group.

I don't mind rewriting the whole line, but how do I get sed to match on that expression - it doesn't seem to like capture groups or backreferences (at least, the way I'm trying it: I [know it does](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html)). I get an unhelpful

```
syntax error near unexpected token `)'
```

Also how can I capture the file name and then pipe its contents back in as the replacement line?

Comment: What is the full `sed` command that is giving you the error message? What version of `sed` are you using?

Comment: sed on osx (so bsd); trying `sed -E 's/<script\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?src=(["'])(.*?)\1/whatever/' file.html`; trying to escape that single quote with `\'` or \x27 isn't happening

Comment: Regardless of `sed`, you need to replace `'` with `'\''` when you try to write single quotes in single quoted strings.

Comment: yes. if i reverse the quoting and escape `sed -E "s/<script\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?src=(["'])(.*?)\1/whatever/" file.html` yields  `RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid` which is normally missing `-r` but `-E` should cover that

Comment: * `["']` supposed to be `[\"']` of course, but it still has the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) instead:

```
awk '
    match($0, "<script src=." jsfile ".></script>") {
        print "<script>"
        while (getline line < jsfile) print line
        print "</script>"
        next
    }
    {print}
' jsfile=foo.js file.html
```

which outputs

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href="blah.css">
<script>
var foo = {};
var bar = [];
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bar.js"></script>
<title />
```

To save the output back to the original html file:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
awk ... > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" file.html
```

Comment: great! i've heard of `awk` for a while but never really used it. this example provides exactly what I need to get started. Cheers!

Comment: I started off trying to solve it with sed, but I couldn't quite get the output in the right order.